# Java : incompatible types; int cannot be converted to string

Tags: java, types, stream

Im just trying to send an integer from my server to my client via sockets.

```
public static DataOutputStream toClient = null;
public static int clients = 0;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1039);
        System.out.println("Server is running..");

        while (true) {
            Socket connsock = null;
            try {
                // accepting client socket
                connsock = serverSocket.accept();

                toClient = new DataOutputStream(connsock.getOutputStream());
                
                System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + connsock);

                clients = clients + 1;
                toClient.writeUTF(clients); //here, I get the incompatible types; int cannot be converted to string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

> incompatible types; int cannot be converted to string

on the line with `toClient.writeUTF(clients);`.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `writeUTF` of [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) is expecting a `String` while you provided an `int`.

When you want to send an `int`, I would consider the following two options:

- continue to use `writeUTF()`, but then you have to convert `clients` to an `int` using `String.valueOf(clients)`.
- use `writeInt` instead to send a plain `int` instead of a `String`.

Summary:

```
// convert to String
toClient.writeUTF(String.valueOf(clients));
// send a single plain int value
toClient.writeInt(clients);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because writeUTF in DataOutputStream doesnt have an overloaded method which accepts int. So you will need to convert your int to String : Integer.toString(i)

Answer (score 0):

The `writeUTF` method takes string arguments but your `clients` variable in your code is an integer type.

Here's the signature:

```java
public final void writeUTF(String str) throws IOException {
    writeUTF(str, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toClient.writeUTF(clients);
```

Here writeUTF(String str) takes string type parameter so you have to change clients integer to string type.